# Halting inevitably leads to reboot

Tags: raspbian, power

I always shut down the system with `halt`, which is the equivalent of `shutdown -h now`.  On every linux system I've ever used, including up until recently the pi, this halts the system and turns off the power if the hardware is capable.

On the pi -- again, up until recently -- it just shuts the system down so that the power can be unplugged.  I generally leave it on 24/7, but occasionally I want to disconnect it from power to tinker or whatever.  Sometime in the past few months, I noticed that it was rebooting immediately, and I kind of shrugged it off; I have an 8x8 LED attached as a system monitor, so I'd wait until it signaled runlevel 0 had run then yank the cord.

That's not really ideal IMO, and I am *absolutely completely totally positive* it was not doing this until recently; I've had the pi for the better part of a year.
I just spent some time using `shutdown` with various switches (`-h`, `-f`, `-P`, `-n`) and combinations of switches, and **none** of them will halt the system without triggering an immediate reboot.<sup>1</sup>

My first thought is that something is causing a quick voltage drop and that triggers the reboot, but that's just a thought.  So my questions are:

1. Has anyone else noticed this?
2. Does anyone have any idea about why it would happen? A recent firmware update? *[As it turns out, I hadn't been updating the firmware -- see my answer]*.

---

<sup>1</sup> Correction : `shutdown -fn now` will halt it, although this means skipping the init scripts intended to stop services correctly (BTW I don't see anything in `/etc/rc0.d` that would cause the reboot) and mysteriously leaves the board's ethernet lights on, presumably because the networking service was not properly stopped.

Comment: I did some testing with my Raspberry Pi, and it did not experience the behavior your are describing, odd.

Comment: @syb0rg : Yeah, this is for sure a fairly recent change in behavior.

Comment: Any chance, Wake-On-LAN is causing this? Is it an immediate reboot?

Comment: I can't find anyone claiming to have actually gotten WOL to work on the pi, so if it is I guess I am lucky, ;).  Anyway, it's an immediate reboot, yeah.

Comment: Does it also happen if you disconnect all USB, GPIO, and network cables?

Comment: @Gerben : The only thing I've tried disconnecting is the audio jack, since I recently started using a different amp with it.  Everything else is the same as before the problem started, except one 3.3V I2C device -- but I haven't tried detaching the GPIO leads yet because I have to dissemble the case first; I should get around to that soon.

Comment: I've also noticed this happening on one of my two Raspberry Pis just recently. I've updated both to the latest software and firmware but this has not changed the situation. The one that reboots after halting is a later version model B with the 512K ram. The old one with 256K ram still halt properly. Is it possible that some minor HW difference interacting with a recent software upgrade is causing this ??

Comment: I was having the identical issue. sudo shutdown -h now
resultes in a reboot. However, sudo shutdown -P now
works. Weird, but there you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed and ran `rpi-update`.  This replaced a lot of files in `/boot`, and, I noticed, installed a lot of modules for a 3.10.24+ kernel, which I wasn't aware existed (my git clone of the archive was fixed on 3.6.11, and that's the latest one I had on the pi).

So I built 3.10.24+ (the [current stable for the pi](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux)) using `/proc/config.gz` from my 3.6.11 kernel -- i.e., I did not change the configuration at all.  This potentially overwrote the stuff in `/lib/modules/3.10.24+` installed by `rpi-update`, so I ran that again (first removing `/boot/.firmware_revision` to make it do everything over).  Unfortunately, the modules from rpi-update did not jibe ("disagrees about version of symbol module_layout").  I couldn't resolve that,<sup>1</sup> so I went back to my vanilla modules directory from the build.

Rebooting at this point solved the problem.  It is worth noting that it persists with the old kernel, so it was not simply a matter of the firmware in `/boot`; also I rebooted after the firmware revision, before building the new kernel.  However, the [rpi-update README](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) does note **"some firmware updates might depend on a kernel update"** (although AFAICT, rpi-update doesn't provide a kernel update!). To summarize:

- Running `rpi-update` with 3.6.11 kernel **did not** fix the problem.
- Installing a 3.10.24+ kernel *after* `rpi-update` **did** fix the problem.  This kernel was built starting with the same `.config` as the 3.6.11 kernel. I did not use the `/lib/modules` stuff installe by rpi-update as the kernel rejected them.
- Reverting to the old kernel causes the problem to return.

I'm perplexed as to why this would have happened in the first place, but it could be that it did start with my last build of 3.6.11; the only difference between that and the previous one was making `i2c-dev` a built-in.

---

<sup>1</sup> Perhaps they are intended for a pre-built kernel available from...somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know the cause of that behaviour, but to shutdown my RPIs, I usually use `poweroff`, which, I think is equivalent to `shutdown -h now`:

```
$ sudo poweroff
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: No such luck!  It's definitely not supposed to be this way.

Comment: `poweroff` and `shutdown` are both links to `systemctl`, so if one command is broken, the other will be broken too.